# Fetch Request VS. WebSocket Which one is faster?

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, fetch

I'm sending a same data in both `Fetch` and `WebSocket` but :

- HTTP takes `29` seconds to transfer around `200 MB`.
- WebSocket takes `6` seconds to transfer around `200 MB`.

#### Question

Why `WebSocket` is faster than `HTTP`?
It's related to encoding or technology or something else...?

#### Fetch

```
 async function postData(url = '', data) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
            },
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
            body: data
        });
        return response; //.arrayBuffer();
    }

    postData('http://localhost:3800/buffer', arrU8)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

`arrU8` is an `Uint8Array` by length : 185578200

#### WebSocket

```
  function connect() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8081/echo');
            ws.onopen = function () {
                resolve(ws);
            };
            ws.onerror = function (err) {
                reject(err);
            };
            ws.onclose = function (evt) {
                console.log("CLOSE SOCKET", new Date().toLocaleString());
            };
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                console.log("RESPONSE SOCKET: " + "RECEIVED" /* evt.data */, new Date().toLocaleString());
            };
        });
    }

    connect().then(function (ws) {
        // onopen
        ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
        ws.send(arrU8);
        ws.close();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        // onerror
        console.log("ERROR: " + evt.data, new Date().toLocaleString());
    });
```

### Server Side is wrote by GO

##### HTTP

```
func process(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    if r.URL.Path != "/buffer" {
        http.Error(w, "404 not found.", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    switch r.Method {
    case "GET":

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "GET request is received: %s \n", r.URL)
    case "POST":

        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        log.Println("Data length received = ", len(body))

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Data length = %v \n", len(body))

    default:
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sorry, only GET and POST methods are supported.")
    }
}
```

##### WebSocket

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var addr = flag.String("addr", "localhost:8081", "http service address")
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{} // use default options
func main() {

    log.Println("Launching WebSocket server...", *addr)
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lmicroseconds)
    http.HandleFunc("/echo", echo)
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, nil))
}

func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // To fix 403 error temporarily. It's unsafe:
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }

    c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()
    for {
        mt, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            break
        }
        log.Println("recv: message type:", mt)
        log.Printf("recv: bytes count: %v", len(message))
        // // // Disable echo and log
        // log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        // err = c.WriteMessage(mt, message)
        // if err != nil {
        //  log.Println("write:", err)
        //  break
        // }
    }
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    homeTemplate.Execute(w, "ws://"+r.Host+"/echo")
}
```

Comment: That depends a lot on the server side too… WebSocket by definition is mostly put straight through packet by packet, while an HTTP request/response may be buffered in its entirety by some intermediate servers. Of course, with the right configuration, you could probably also get HTTP to go straight through. That depends on the details…

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to make our `HTTP Fetch Request` to be at the highest performance ?  @deceze

Comment: Figure out where exactly the bottleneck is first of all. Is the request buffered at certain points? Then that needs to be optimised somehow. Or is the web server simply a lot slower than the web socket server? Then that needs to be changed. **This all depends on a lot of details which you tell us nothing about.**

Comment: The server side snippet code added @deceze

Comment: The websocket client does not wait on the server reading the data. The HTTP client does wait on the server reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Websocket is faster if you have to send more data over time, because you can keep the connection to the server open.

With http you have to make the 2-way handshake everytime and establish a connection every time you want to send something.

In your situation it would be because the http have to make the handshake multiple times, because it can't send everything in one session.

Comment: 1) Keep-Alive is a thing, 2) the overhead of a handshake is negligible compared to the time it takes to transfer 200 MB, except in extremely high-latency situations, 3) why do you need multiple "sessions"?!

Comment: How can we find that `HTTP` How many `session` has used ?